# How does TeX (LaTeX?) center images off the page?

Tags: graphics

I noticed that if I try to center an image that goes off the page, TeX/LaTeX seems to give up and just left-align the image. Why is this?

Comment: You can trick TeX using a box: `\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[scale = 1.5]{example-image-a} }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The basic mechanism by which Tex works is a mechansm known as boxes and glue. Centering is not a primitive operation.

Glue is white space that has a natural length and separate lengths by which it can stretch or shrink.

in LaTeX most centering (say of the letter `X`) is done by placing glue either side that is equivalent to `\hfil` that is `0pt plus 1fil minus 0pt`

So in

```
\hbox to \textwidth{%
\hspace{0pt plus 1fil}X\hspace{0pt plus 1fil}%
}
```

The requested box is `\textwidth` wide, `X` is smaller than that, so the two glue elements expand equally to fill the gap.

But note the minimum glue size on either side is `0pt` so if you replace `X` by something wider than `\textwidth` the box is overfull (and sticks out on the right).

Other choices would be possible, for example the plain Tex macro `\centerline` is similar to the above but uses `\hss` which has infinite stretch *and* shrink values. that allows the text to be wider than the textwidth and the glue automatically assumes negative amounts to compensate. This always centres but you get no warning the text boundaries (or even the page boundaries) have been exceeded.

Comment: Ah, I misread the question. I thought the OP wanted to know how to center an image wider than `\textwidth`. I'll delete my answer and gladly give you my +1 :)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina no I'd leave yours. although phrased as a "why" the Op may want to know how to avoid the problem:-)

Comment: OK. I undeleted it and you still have my +1 :).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina voted:-)

Comment: "sticks out on the left" ... huh?  i'm used to things like this sticking out on the right.

Comment: @barbarabeeton sorry probably confused as I'd just spent the previous half hour reading about Arabic vowels....

Answer (score 8):

[David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228540/3954) nicely explains the centering mechanism. If you want to know one option to center an image wider than `\textwidth`, one possibility is to trick TeX using a box:

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[margin=3cm,showframe]{geometry} 

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[scale = 1.3]{example-image-a} }
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, the best solution is to control the width for the image so it doesn't exceed `\textwidth`:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
```